# Calling a .php document in JavaScript using Django Framework

Tags: javascript, php, django

I'm wondering if this is Django URLs issue. I am following [a Google Tutorial][1] to pop down markers showing addresses on a Google Map pulled from a database using php and xml. I have wired up a .php to my PostgreSQL db okay and seem to be able to run the script and show all the addresses and details in the console (I believe this means the XML file is working too).

**The Problem**

The trouble I am having is on the JavaScript side: I am using downloadURL() function in my .js static file. And pointing the URL parameter to my .php file which is stored in my local directory:

```
var markerurl = 'testingland/www/xmlpgd.php'

downloadUrl(markerurl, function(data)
```

However when I test the script on my local development server (http://127.0.0.1:8000/cafe_list) it returns the following error:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/cafe_list/testingland/www/xmlpgd.php 404 (Not Found)`

**What I have tried**
I have tried moving the xmlpgd.php file to different locations including templates, static and elsewhere. I have tried hosting it on Google Cloud (which returns a CORS error). I am at a loss and thinking maybe I need to wire it up to my urls.py file? I am just not sure whether this is the case or how to do this properly.

**My Code**

Here is my urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('cafe_list/', views.cafes_home, name='cafes_home'),
    url('electra/cafe_list/', views.cafe_list.as_view(), name='cafe_list'),
]
```

Here is my JS Code:

```
//loads map markers from database
                 function downloadUrl(url,callback) {
                   var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                       new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                       new XMLHttpRequest;

                   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                     if (request.readyState == 4) {
                       request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                       callback(request, request.status);
                     }
                   };

                       request.open('GET', url, true);
                       request.send(null);
                      }

//get the markers from php file and adds them to map

                    var markerurl = 'testingland/www/xmlpgd.php';
                    downloadUrl(markerurl, function(data) {
                      var xml = parseXml(data);
                      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
                      Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
                        var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
                        var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
                        var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
                        var type = markerElem.getAttribute('location');
                        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                            parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                            parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

                        var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
                        var strong = document.createElement('strong');
                        strong.textContent = name
                        infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
                        infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                        var text = document.createElement('text');
                        text.textContent = address
                        infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                        var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                          map: map,
                          position: point


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps
```

Comment: I'm wondering why do you want to mix PHP and Python - maybe there's a way to convert that PHP script to Django view? And another question is about web server - do you use nginx or something in front of django application?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am quite new to Django/Python still, so somewhat led by the tutorials as to how to implement features on my webapp. I would prefer not to use the PHP at all if I can, I just don't know where to start. But I had a suspicion I was mixing two languages. 

I am currently just running this on a development server ``python manage.py runserver``

Comment: Could you share your `xmlpgd.php` file? Is it just an xml file? Or maybe you have some logic there. If so, then how do you run that php file? Do you have apache or something to point URL to actual execution of PHP file?